# How do you move an animated rig around the scene?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, transforms, parent

I have made this ''Spider'' rig and animated the ''feet'' bones with a follow path constraint and curves.

When i select the Curves and the armature to move it around, then the whole thing ''streches'' and behaves in weird ways. (somehow its being pulled from the origin)

Extra info: I have tried to add an empty, parent the curves and armature to it and move it around. (Same problem)

btw what are those blue lines? I feel like i should get rid of them, since its pulling in that direction. (im just guessing at this moment)

Thanks

[image: moved forward]

[image: original position]

Comment: This looks neat! I tried to recreate your issue but I can't figure out your setup from the images. Could you provide an example file?

Comment: @Zoukeau Thanks for reaching out! Really appreciate your help. 


Here is a wetreansfer download link for the example file:



[Example File](https://we.tl/t-3QLim1Whqe)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to put together an answer tomorrow. However I can already tell you that the dotted blue lines are there because of the empty rotation constraints that you have on each curve object, by removing those you also remove the dotted blue lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the culprit, all these curves have been rotated 90° on the X axis:

[image: 1]

By applying this rotation with Ctrl+A -> Rotation. The foot bone will then point up, by resetting its rotation with Alt+R it'll point the right way again. After doing this for every curve and foot bone we can now move around the armature:

[image: 2]

As you can tell the curves are staying in place, by parenting them to an empty object or to the armature you once again get unpredictable behaviour. Honestly the Follow Path constraint for bones feels like it lacks some options, the Follow Path constraint for objects works more reliably. You could put this constraint on those little Lego-brick feet and then parent the foot bones to the them, or remove the foot bones and use the feet as targets for your IK constraints instead.

A third option would be to avoid using Follow Path constraints altogether and animate it:

[image: 3]

This armature can be moved around without issue, here's [the updated file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUJ8SnstzM0Yp8F-NQ_OhtR9ybtKI7Cq/view?usp=share_link) Hope that helps.

Comment: Bro not only did this help, i learned soooo much from your reply! Thank you so much for real.

Feel free to use that rig+model if you needed it!